# one js function call in multiple elements, jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, timer

I have a table with many rows. In each row I have to show a countdown timer with given value.

This is my js function in jsp.

```
<script>
function start(initial_time) {
    var initialTime = initial_time.value;

        tick();
        setInterval(function () {
            tick();
            if (initialTime < -1) reset();
            if (initialTime < 6) paint("red")
        }, 1000)

    function tick() {
        document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = initialTime.toString();
        --initialTime;
    }

    function reset() {
        initialTime = 30;
        tick();
        paint("black");
    }

    function paint(color) {
        document.getElementById("time").style.color = color;
    }
}
```

This is my table row in the same jsp page

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" align="center">
<tbody >
<c:forEach items="${data.getCards()}" var="card">
    <tr>
        <td style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 30px; text-align: left; width: 100%; background-color: #78909C;"
            colspan="4">${card.getLocationName()}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 24px; text-align: left; width: 70%; background-color: #b0bec5;"
            colspan="3">Time left for next density check
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 22px; text-align: left; width: 30%; background-color: #b0bec5;" colspan="1">
            <div id="time" onload="start(${card.getDefaultServerDensityValue()})"></div>                <input hidden="hidden" id="density" value="${card.getDefaultServerDensityValue()}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Seems ok but timers in rows does'n shown up, does anybody knows why?

Comment: Did you log into the console the value of initialTime.toString()?

Comment: Yes I did, it reads, did a lot of experiments to be sure it reads the value, so we can exclude not reading the value version.

Comment: Even when I add just a number it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Try to inspect with a dom inspector to check the element is visible

Comment: Did, it is visible and reads the value.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure Should be in JSP.

```
<table id="mytable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" align="center">
<tbody >
<c:forEach items="${data.getCards()}" var="card">
    <tr>
        <td style="table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: middle; font-size: 30px; text-align: left; width: 100%; background-color: #78909C;"
            colspan="4">${card.getLocationName()}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 24px; text-align: left; width: 70%; background-color: #b0bec5;"
            colspan="3">Time left for next density check
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle; font-size: 22px; text-align: left; width: 30%; background-color: #b0bec5;" colspan="1">
            <div data-timer="${card.getDefaultServerDensityValue()}"></div>                <input hidden="hidden" id="density" value="${card.getDefaultServerDensityValue()}"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

You Jquery code Should be

```
<script>
function start(initial_time, ele) {
    var initialTime = parseInt(initial_time);

        tick();
        setInterval(function () {
            tick();
            if (initialTime < -1) reset();
            if (initialTime < 6) paint("red")
        }, 1000)

    function tick() {
        ele.innerHTML = initialTime.toString();
        --initialTime;
    }

    function reset() {
        initialTime = 30;
        tick();
        paint("black");
    }

    function paint(color) {
        ele.style.color = color;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#my_table tbody td[data-timer]").each(function(){
         start($(this).data("timer"),$(this)[0]);
    });
})
```

Comment: It seem that my jsp page doesn't recognize "$", do I have to import anything ?

Comment: can you put your produced HTML code instead of JSP code?

Comment: Do you mean put simple number instead of ${card.getDefaultServerDensityValue()}  this ?

Comment: Actually, I am not JSP developer, I am php developer so I have tried my best for that... if you put your source code in put HTML format then I can get idea what is error or bug,.

Comment: thank you i appreciate it ) really
Actually it is html just in jsp file so for me to be able to include some java code.

Answer (score 0):

This is how finally it was got done.
JQuery part

```
<script>
function start(initial_time, ele) {
    var initialTime = parseInt(initial_time);

    tick();
    setInterval(function () {
        tick();
        if (initialTime < -1) reset();
        if (initialTime < 6) paint("red")
    }, 1000)

    function tick() {
        ele.innerHTML = initialTime.toString();
        --initialTime;
    }

    function reset() {
        initialTime = initial_time;
        tick();
        paint("red");
    }

    function paint(color) {
        ele.style.color = color;
    }
}

(function() {

    $("#mytable").find("div[data-timer]").each(function(){
        start($(this).data("timer"),$(this)[0]);
    });
})();
```

For those who is as new to JQuery as I am, you need to incl;ude in your JSP page Jquery libs this way

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>`
```

Include after `<head>` tag

In JSP your timer element will look like

```
<div data-timer="${card.getDefaultServerDensityValue()}"></div>
```

You can use any other element instead of `<div>` .

Also make sure to give an id to your table

```
<table id="mytable" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; table-layout: fixed;" align="center">
```

And make sure that id of table matches with `$("#mytable")` in javascript.

Result is 
[image]

Where red numbers are counting down.